# Family-in-law terms

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

**Are these terms OK?**

Father-in-law (my wife's father) = 장인 어른

Father-in-law (my husband's father) = 아버님

Mother-in-law (my wife's mother) = 장모님

Mother-in-law (my husband's mother) = 어머님

Brother-in-law (my wife's older brother) = 처남

Brother-in-law (my wife's younger brother) = 처남

Sister-in-law (my wife's older sister) = 처형

Sister-in-law (my wife's younger sister) = 처제

Brother-in-law (my husband's older brother) = 시아주버니

Brother-in-law (my husband's younger brother) = 시동생

Sister-in-law (my husband's older sister) = 시누이

Sister-in-law (my husband's younger sister) = 시누이

I would also like to know if terms for "brother-in-law" and "sister-in-law" also vary depending on whether they are married or not. If they do, **could somebody add variations between married and unmarried in terms where necessary?**

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm Korean, but I still don't know family term properly. This is just too hard. ...But at list I can google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are quotations from one of the guides entitled "표준 언어 예절" (2011). I have translated them into English for you. I noticed that their tables have a few errors, so you should *not* trust all this information. Nonetheless, I do *not* believe that all Koreans know and follow the whole usage. The National Institute of Korean Language is currently revising them. Hence, some parts of the following may have to be edited sooner or later.

```
  A: addressed as
  M: mentioned as
  ○○: your child's first name (one's first name has one, two, three, four, or five characters)
  ○○P: the name of the place where he lives (e.g. 서울, 부산, 제주)
  ○: his last name (one's last name has one or two characters)
```

## **father-in-law**

1. the father of your husband (if you are a woman)

   - A: 아버님
   - M to him: 아버님
   - M to his wife: 아버님
   - M to his parents: 아버님 or 아버지
   - M to your husband: 아버님
   - M to your husband's siblings and their spouses: 아버님
   - M to your child(ren): 할아버지 or 할아버님
   - M to your husband's other blood relatives: 아버님
   - M to your other blood relatives: 시아버님, 시아버지, ○○ 할아버지, or ○○ 할아버님
   - M to the others: 시아버님, 시아버지, 아버님, ○○ 할아버지, or ○○
     할아버님
2. the father of your wife (if you are a man)

   - A: 장인어른 or 아버님
   - M to him and his wife: 장인어른 or 아버님
   - M to your wife: 장인어른, 아버님, or 장인
   - M to your wife's siblings and their spouses: 장인어른 or 아버님
   - M to your child(ren): 외할아버지 or 외할아버님
   - M to your other blood relatives (including your parents and siblings): 장인, 장인어른, or ○○ 외할아버지
   - M to the others: 장인, 장인어른, ○○ 외할아버지, or ○○ 외할아버님

## mother-in-law

1. the mother of your husband (if you are a woman)

   - A: 어머님 or 어머니
   - M to her: 어머님 or 어머니
   - M to her husband: 어머님 or 어머니
   - M to her parents: 어머님 or 어머니
   - M to your husband: 어머님
   - M to your husband's siblings and their spouses: 어머님
   - M to your child(ren): 할머니 or 할머님
   - M to your husband's other blood relatives: 어머님
   - M to your other blood relatives: 시어머님, 시어머니, ○○ 할머니, or ○○ 할머님
   - M to the others: 시어머님, 시어머니, 어머님, ○○ 할머니, or ○○ 할머님
2. the mother of your wife (if you are a man)

   - A: 장모님 or 어머님
   - M to her: 장모님 or 어머님
   - M to her husband: 장모님 or 어머님
   - M to your wife: 장모님, 어머님, or 장모
   - M to your wife's siblings and their spouses: 장모님 or 어머님
   - M to your child(ren): 외할머니 or 외할머님
   - M to your other blood relatives (including your parents and siblings): 장모, 장모님, or ○○ 외할머니
   - M to the others: 장모, 장모님, ○○ 외할머니, or ○○ 외할머님

## brother-in-law

1. the brother of your husband (if you are a woman)

   1. the older brother of your husband

      - A: 아주버님
      - M to him: 아주버님
      - M to your child(ren): 큰아버지 or 큰아버님
      - M to your husband's other blood relatives: 아주버님
      - M to the others (including your other blood relatives): 시아주버니 or ○○ 큰아버지
   2. the younger brother of your husband

      - A: 도련님 if he is unmarried and 서방님 if he is married
      - M to him: 도련님 if he is unmarried and 서방님 if he is married
      - M to your child(ren): 작은아버지, 작은아버님 or 삼촌
      - M to your husband's other blood relatives: 도련님 if he is unmarried and 서방님 if he is married
      - M to your other blood relatives: 시동생, ○○ 작은아버지, or ○○ 삼촌
      - M to the others: 도련님 if he is unmarried and 서방님 if he is married, or 시동생, ○○ 작은아버지, or ○○ 삼촌
2. the brother of your wife (if you are a man)

   1. the older brother of your wife

      - A: 형님 (or 처남 if he is younger than you)
      - M to him: 형님 (or 처남 if he is younger than you)
      - M to your wife: 형님 (or 처남 if he is younger than you)
      - M to your wife's parents: 형님
      - M to your wife's older siblings and their spouses: 형님 (or 처남 if he is younger than you)
      - M to your wife's younger brothers and the husbands of your wife's younger sisters: 형님 or 형
      - M to your wife's younger sisters and the wives of your wife's younger brothers: 오빠
      - M to your child(ren): 외삼촌, 외숙부, or 외숙부님
      - M to the others (including your parents and siblings): 처남 or ○○ 외삼촌
   2. the younger brother of your wife

      - A: 처남
      - M to him: 처남 or 자네
      - M to your wife: 처남
      - M to your wife's parents: 처남
      - M to your wife's older siblings and their spouses: 처남
      - M to your wife's younger siblings older than him and their spouses older than him: 처남, 동생
      - M to your wife's younger brothers younger than him and your wife's younger sisters' husbands younger than him: 형 or 형님
      - M to your wife's younger sisters younger than him and your wife's younger brothers' wives younger than him: 오빠
      - M to your child(ren): 외삼촌, 외숙부, or 외숙부님
      - M to the others (including your parents and siblings): 처남 or ○○ 외삼촌
3. the husband of your sister (if you are a woman)

   1. the husband of your older sister

      - A: 형부
      - M to him: 형부
      - M to your child(ren): 이모부 or 이모부님
      - M to your parents and siblings, and to the spouses of your siblings: 형부
      - M to the others (including your husband's other blood relatives): 형부 or ○○ 이모부
   2. the husband of your younger sister

      - A: ○ 서방 or 제부
      - M to him: ○ 서방 or 제부
      - M to your child(ren): 이모부
      - M to your parents and siblings, and to the spouses of your siblings: ○ 서방 or 제부
      - M to the others (including your husband's other blood relatives): 동생 남편, 동생의 남편, ○○ 이모부, or 제부
4. the husband of your sister (if you are a man)

   1. the husband of your older sister

      - A: 매형, 자형, or 매부
      - M to him: 매형, 자형, or 매부
      - M to your child(ren): 고모부 or 고모부님
      - M to your parents and siblings, and to the spouses of your siblings: 매형, 자형, or 매부
      - M to the others (including your wife's other blood relatives): 매형, 자형, 매부, ○○ 고모부
   2. the husband of your younger sister

      - A: ○ 서방, 매부, or 매제
      - M to him: ○ 서방, 매부, or 매제
      - M to your child(ren): 고모부
      - M to your parents and siblings, and to the spouses of your siblings: ○ 서방, 매부, or 매제
      - M to your wife's other blood relatives: 매부, 매제, or ○○ 고모부
      - M to the others: ○ 서방, 매부, 매제, or ○○ 고모부
5. the husband of your husband's sister (if you are a woman)

   1. the husband of your husband's older sister

      - A: 아주버님
      - M to him: 아주버님
      - M to your child(ren): 고모부 or 고모부님
      - M to the others: 시누이 남편, 아주버님, ○○P 아주버님, ○○ 고모부, or ○○ 고모부님
   2. the husband of your husband's younger sister

      - A: 서방님
      - M to him: 서방님
      - M to your child(ren): 고모부 or 고모부님
      - M to the others: 시누이 남편, 서방님, ○○P 서방님, ○ 서방, ○○ 고모부, or ○○ 고모부님
6. the husband of your wife's sister (if you are a man)

   1. the husband of your wife's older sister

      - A: 형님 (or 동서 if he is younger than you)
      - M to him: 형님 (or 동서 if he is younger than you)
      - M to your wife: 형님 (or 동서 if he is younger than you)
      - M to your wife's parents: 형님
      - M to your wife's older siblings and their spouses: 형님
      - M to your wife's younger brothers and the husbands of your wife's younger sisters: 매형, 자형, or 매부
      - M to your wife's younger sisters and the wives of your wife's younger brothers: 형부
      - M to your child(ren): 이모부 or 이모부님
      - M to the others (including your parents and siblings): 동서 or ○○ 이모부
   2. the husband of your wife's younger sister

      - A: 동서 or ○ 서방
      - M to him: 동서 or ○ 서방
      - M to your wife: 동서 or ○ 서방
      - M to your wife's parents: 동서 or ○ 서방
      - M to your wife's older siblings and their spouses: 동서 or ○ 서방
      - M to your wife's younger brothers and the husbands of your
        wife's younger sisters: 매형, 자형, or 매부
      - M to your wife's younger sisters and the wives of your
        wife's younger brothers: 형부
      - M to your child(ren): 이모부 or 이모부님
      - M to the others (including your parents and siblings): 동서 or ○○ 이모부

## sister-in-law

1. the sister of your husband (if you are a woman)

   1. the older sister of your husband

      - A: 형님
      - M to her: 형님
      - M to your child(ren): 고모 or 고모님
      - M to your husband's other blood relatives: 형님
      - M to the others (including your other blood relatives): 시누이, 형님, or ○○ 고모
   2. the younger sister of your husband

      - A: 아가씨 or 아기씨
      - M to her: 아가씨 or 아기씨
      - M to your child(ren): 고모 or 고모님
      - M to your husband's other blood relatives: 아가씨 or 아기씨
      - M to your other blood relatives: 시누이 or ○○ 고모
      - M to the others: 시누이, 아가씨, 아기씨, or ○○ 고모
2. the sister of your wife (if you are a man)

   1. the older sister of your wife

      - A: 처형
      - M to her: 처형
      - M to your wife: 처형
      - M to your wife's parents: 처형
      - M to your wife's older siblings and their spouses: 처형
      - M to your wife's younger brothers and the husbands of your wife's younger sisters: 누나 or 누님
      - M to your wife's younger sisters and the wives of your wife's younger brothers: 언니
      - M to your child(ren): 이모 or 이모님
      - M to the others (including your parents and siblings): 처형 or ○○ 이모
   2. the younger sister of your wife

      - A: 처제
      - M to her: 처제
      - M to your wife: 처제
      - M to your wife's parents: 처제
      - M to your wife's older siblings and their spouses: 처제
      - M to your wife's younger siblings older than her and their spouses older than her: 처제 or 동생
      - M to your wife's younger brothers younger than her and your wife's younger sisters' husbands younger than her: 누나 or 누님
      - M to your wife's younger sisters younger than her and your wife's younger brothers' wives younger than her: 언니
      - M to your child(ren): 이모 or 이모님
      - M to the others (including your parents and siblings): 처제 or ○○ 이모
3. the wife of your brother (if you are a woman)

   1. the wife of your older brother (regardless of her age)

      - A: 새언니 or 언니
      - M to her: 새언니 or 언니
      - M to your child(ren): 외숙모 or 외숙모님
      - M to your parents and siblings, and to the spouses of your siblings: 새언니, 언니, 올케, or 올케언니
      - M to the others (including your husband's other blood relatives): 올케, 올케언니, 새언니, or ○○ 외숙모
   2. the wife of your younger brother

      - A: 올케
      - M to her: 올케
      - M to your child(ren): 외숙모
      - M to your parents and siblings, and to the spouses of your siblings: 올케
      - M to the others (including your husband's other blood relatives): 올케 or ○○ 외숙모
4. the wife of your brother (if you are a man)

   1. the wife of your older brother

      - A: 형수님, 아주머님, or 아주머니
      - M to her: 형수님, 아주머님, or 아주머니
      - M to your parents: 형수, 아주머니
      - M to your siblings and their spouses: 형수님, 형수, 아주머님, or 아주머니
      - M to your child(ren): 큰어머니 or 큰어머님
      - M to your wife's other blood relatives: 형수님, 아주머님, 아주머니, or ○○ 큰어머니
      - M to the others: 형수님, ○○ 큰어머니
   2. the wife of your younger brother

      - A: 제수씨 or 계수씨
      - M to her: 제수씨 or 계수씨
      - M to your child(ren): 작은어머니 or 숙모
      - M to your parents and siblings, and to the spouses of your siblings: 제수, 제수씨, 계수, or 계수씨
      - M to the others (including your wife's other blood relatives): 제수, 제수씨, 계수, 계수씨, ○○ 작은어머니
5. the wife of your husband's brother (if you are a woman)

   1. the wife of your husband's older brother

      - A: 형님
      - M to her: 형님
      - M to your child(ren): 큰어머니 or 큰어머님
      - M to your husband's other blood relatives: 형님
      - M to the others (including your other blood relatives): 큰동서, 형님, or ○○ 큰어머니, or 맏동서 only if she is the wife of your husband's oldest brother
   2. the wife of your husband's younger bother

      - A: 동서
      - M to her: 동서
      - M to your child(ren): 작은어머니 or 작은어머님
      - M to your husband's other blood relatives: 동서
      - M to the others (including your other blood relatives): 동서, 작은동서, or ○○ 작은어머니
6. the wife of your wife's brother (if you are a man)

   1. the wife of your wife's older brother

      - A: 아주머니
      - M to her: 아주머니
      - M to your wife: 처남댁 or 처남의 댁
      - M to your wife's parents: 처남댁 or 처남의 댁
      - M to your wife's older siblings and their spouses: 처남댁 or
        처남의 댁
      - M to your wife's younger siblings and their spouses: 형수,
        새언니, 언니, 올케, or 올케언니
      - M to your child(ren): 외숙모 or 외숙모님
      - M to the others (including your parents and siblings): 처남댁, 처남의 댁, or ○○ 외숙모
   2. the wife of your wife's younger brother

      - A: 처남댁 or 처남의 댁
      - M to her: 처남댁 or 처남의 댁
      - M to your wife: 처남댁 or 처남의 댁
      - M to your wife's parents: 처남댁 or 처남의 댁
      - M to your wife's older siblings and their spouses: 처남댁 or 처남의 댁
      - M to your wife's younger siblings and their spouses: 형수, 새언니, 언니, 올케, or 올케언니
      - M to your child(ren): 외숙모 or 외숙모님
      - M to the others (including your parents and siblings): 처남댁, 처남의 댁, or ○○ 외숙모

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it is really helpful!! I greatly appreciate it! 대단히 감사합니다

Answer (score 0):

notation : W = girl, M = man

**brother in law**

1) 매형 = M's older sister's husband

That is, M call the husband 매형 and conversely, 매형 call M 처남.

M's wife's older brother is 형님

매제 = M's younger sister's husband.

2) There are two sisters : Older's husband call younger's husband 동서
and conversely, 형님

3) 형부 = W's older sister's husband

제부 = W's younger sister's husband

4) 시숙 = W's husband's brother

Here older is 아주버니 and younger is 시동생 Here when 시동생 is
 not married, then he is 도련님

**Sister in law**

1) 처형 = Wife's older sister

처제 = Wife's younger sister

2) There are two brothers : Older's wife call younger's wife 동서
and conversely, 형님

3) 시누이 = husband's older or younger sister

올케 = W's older or younger brother's wife

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Just some questions, are the terms for "father-in-law" and "mother-in-law" OK? And how would you say "M's older brother's wife" and "M's younger brother wife"?